# How can i prevent swearwords on the server on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to block messages which contain swearwords.Swearwords in a text file btw.So,I got stuck because whenever I write swearwords,bot doesn't response my message.This is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):   

    global swearword_count
    global badwords
    
    if message.author == client.user:  
        await client.process_commands(message)

    else:
        msg = message.content
        for x in msg:

            try:

                if x in badwords:
                    if exception_counter[str(message.author.id)] == 0:
                        await message.channel.send("Please do not use this word ever")
                        swearword_count[str(message.author.id)] += 1
                    if swearword_count[str(message.author.id)] > 5 and exception_counter == 1:
                        await message.author.send("You've been banned due to bad words that you used.")
                    elif swearword_count[str(message.author.id)] > 5 and exception_counter == 0:
                        await message.author.send("You've been banned due to bad words that you used.")

                    await message.channel.send("Don't use this word")


                else:
                    pass

            except KeyError:
                exception_handling[str(message.author.id)] = 1
                swearword_count[str(message.author.id)] = 0
                await message.author.send("If you use this word,you will get banned.")
                continue
        await client.process_commands(message)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member): 
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="welcome")
    await channel.send(f"{member.name},welcome :)")
    global swearword_count
    swearword_count[str(member.id)] = 0
    exception_handling[str(member.id)] = 0
    dm_channell = await member.create_dm()
    await dm_channell.send(f"{member},welcome mate :)")
```

I've used dictionaries to store the data of users.So how can i fix this problem?If you have any advice,I'd love to see it

PS:My commands work properly.

Comment: It looks like message.content is a stream or list of characters.  You need to break it up into words before you start looking them up in the bad words list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `for x in msg:` splits your message into single letters. You have to slice it for example by spaces: `for x in msg.split(" "):`, but this way if someone writes "badword" without spaces (ex. "*badword*Ilikeapples) this won't work. So try this:

```
for x in badwords:
    try:
        if x in msg:
            ...
```

This will catch all the "badwords", but if you write a word that contains the swear word inside it this will also be caught.

Comment: Also, this might be worth mentioning. The `for loop` goes one by one for all the swear words, so if you have multiple swear words in one message they will be caught multiple times, so you might want to move code that sends messages after `for loop` or use `break` statement after catching the swear word, so you won't send the messages multiple times or count all the swear words because someone can get banned after one message.